# Ужасное качество стрима экрана (linux)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, skype

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда включаю стрим экрана, собеседник не может даже текст прочитать - настолько плохое качество. При этом соединение хорошее, при стриме с его экрана все видно превосходно (первые пару секунд может быть немного размыто, но потом улучшается). В чем дело и каково решение?